# How to render components with array of objects in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

To setup my issue:
I want to sort a text-document with regions of texts.
the structure of data is:

```
{"words": ["Horn ", "Cirque ", "Glacier in Longitudinal Section "] }
{"words": ["my other ", "line ", "of texts"] }
```

inside an array.
The result must be rendered in React using a webComponent for each sentence:

```
textContent.map((sentences, index) =>
              <article>
               <desc-sentence>{sentences}</desc-sentence>
              </article>

          )
```

**textContent** is the variable containing each sentence in regions.

but Objects are not valid as Children in react. An array is way recommanded, how to pass array with indexes ?

*Edit

the output shoud be

```js
let textContent = [
     {"words": ["Horn ", "Cirque ", "Glacier in Longitudinal Section "]},
     {"words": ["V-shaped valley ", "carved by a river "]}
]

console.log(textContent[0].words);
```

```html
<section>
<!-- inside the textContent loop of words-->
<article>
  <p>{sentence}</p>  
  <p>{sentence}</p>
 </article>
 <article>
  <p>{sentence}</p>  
  <p>{sentence}</p>
 </article>
</section>
```

Comment: What is the expected/wanted output? Can you write the wanted output html after the render?

Comment: Can you show  the structure of `textContent`

Comment: What does `sentences` look like?

Comment: I have now set an exemple of output and structure of textContent

Comment: @aurny2420289 Do you want it to be like: 
`<article>
  <p>Horn</p>  
  <p>Cirque</p>
  <p>Glacier in Longitudinal Section</p>
 </article>`
?

Comment: @armanshu yes it is the wonder rendering, in loop of others articles containing each sentences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the same code based on your requirement.You can check the HTML structure I think it's mostly what you want  tag has all the names wrapped it in

```js
import React from 'react'
class TestJS extends React.Component {
    render(){
        let textContent = [
            {"words": ["Horn ", "Cirque ", "Glacier in Longitudinal Section "]},
            {"words": ["V-shaped valley ", "carved by a river "]}
        ];
        
        let finalStringMessage = [];
        let textContentLength = textContent.length;
        for(let i=0; i < textContentLength; i++){
            let wordsArray = textContent[i].words;
            let articleName = wordsArray.map((sentences, index) =>
                    <desc-sentence>{sentences}</desc-sentence>

            );
            finalStringMessage.push(<article>{articleName}</article>)
        }
        return(
            <div>{finalStringMessage}</div>
        )
    }
}

export default TestJS;
```

Comment: Thank you, it's the answer i was looking for. is it possible to apply this code to  ReactDOM.render(
            <section>{finalStringMessage}</section>,
            document.getElementById('texte-image')
          ); ?